# How to prove that all the points in the plane are assigned the same value satisfying the given properties?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Each point in the plane is assigned a real number such that, for any triangle, the number at the center of its inscribed circle is equal to the arithmetic mean of the three numbers at its vertices. Prove that all points in the plane are assigned the same number.

How do I even start solving this? I am unable to find a relation between the number assigned to the vertices of a triangle along with its incentre?

Comment: You simply cut and pasted this from Problem 6 from the 2001 USAMO, no effort of your own at all.  If that's your approach to solving problems you might as well cut and paste into Google....you'll find complete solutions easily.

Comment: I have a problem getting a start for the problem and proceeding with the solution. My specific problem is that how do I establish a relation between a 'value' assigned to a point and the vertices of the triangle of which it acts as an incentre. I did get an idea, that a given point can be the incentre for an infinite number of triangle but I find it quite insufficient to prove the given statement.